# Javascript - how do i set the 'this' variable for a function

Tags: javascript

I have a function which takes a callback function.  How can I set the 'this' variable of the callback function?

eg.

```
function(fn){
    //do some stuff
    fn(); //call fn, but the 'this' var is set to window
    //, how do I set it to something else
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you can execute a function in the context of an object using [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Function/call):

```
fn.call( obj, 'param' )
```

There's also [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Function/apply)

Only difference is the syntax for feeding arguments.

Answer (score 2):

You can use either [apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Function/apply) or [call(](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Function/call)).

Either allows you to execute a function with your choice of what `this` is inside the function. `Apply` takes the arguments for the function as an array, while `call` allows you to specify them individually.

Answer (score 2):

```
funct.call(objThatWillBeThis, arg1, ..., argN);
```

or

```
funct.apply(objThatWillBeThis, arrayOfArgs);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use either .call() or .apply().  Depending on your requirement.  [Here](http://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2007/07/05/function-apply-and-function-call-in-javascript.aspx) is an article about them.

Basically you want:

```
function(fn){
    //do some stuff
    fn.call( whateverToSetThisTo ); //call fn, 

}
```